# Im Building A Library

Tags: product-recommendation

So, I am planning this year to build my very own personal dream library with the best seferim. Money is not an issue, and Im willing to spend over 100k just to get everything that a student would dream to have. Ive only ever been exposed to Artscrolls sets like the various commentaries on the Chumash and also the Talmuds but I am going to learn Hebrew and Aramaic very well so I want to buy the best editions for myself so I am not worried about buying Hebrew editions as these are definently the way to get more knowledge.

Firstly, list out the best Talmud Bavli and Yerushalami Sets I can get (I dont care if it costs me over 10k just want everything)

Chumash and if it is possible ( I am not aware bc I only use artscroll) I want a book that has all the commenaries on the Chumash and also if there can be a super commentary book for Rashi and Ramban and other promenent rabbis.

Also for entire Tanach even if it is on every sefer

Shulchan Aruch best set out there
And if possible, sefers for prominent commantaries with super commenaries

Mishnah
Commantries with super commentaries

Mishneh Torah best set out there
Commantries with super commentaries

Zohar
I dont know if there is even a proper and exeptable commentary but list those.

List everything else that is essential and best set for that but these are just some that I really want. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: These questions tend to be closed as best means different things to different people. Unless you have specific criteria it is hard to answer

Comment: Very exciting! But this is a big project and I think you probably need to hire someone to guide you through it. I'm available at a reasonable rate and you can reach me at manorconsortium@gmail.com.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my dream list: [Disclaimer: Links are for illustration purposes only. Other stores may have better prices, service, etc.]

Talmud Bavli: Oz Vehadar set the standard for quality at previously unseen levels; everyone else is playing catch up.

If you want a translation, most people I know use Artscroll. Other translations are more controversial.

Chumash: There are too many to count, but you want to start with a Mikraos Gedolos, for a collection of the main commentaries. I personally prefer Torat Chaim from Mosad Harav Kook. You could also get Artscroll or Oz Vehadar.
For a Chumash with supercommentaries on Rashi, you definitely want this [set](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/chumash-oztar-meforshei-rashi-hameoros-hagedolim-7-volume-set/45007?gclid=CjwKCAiAxP2eBhBiEiwA5puhNUmUFa1R-FlQn4ht4O74VNhoKtys2SaTNFWbnqB1KptbqgbD4v64uhoCJR4QAvD_BwE).

I would also recommend a set of Malbim, because it includes classic Halachic Midrashim in an easy to use format.

There are several different commentaries on Ramban in English or Hebrew. The Artscroll one is probably a good bet. Or the Chavel edition, in English or Hebrew.

For Tanach, any new edition of Mikraos Gedolos. You might also enjoy a set of Me'am Loez.

Other classics on Tanach: Abarbanel, Alshich, and Vilna Gaon.

There are several great sets of Shulchan Aruch. I recommend trying to look at a few yourself, since being comfortable with the print will make a tremendous difference. You might also want to consider getting one set of Tur and Shulchan Aruch combined.
Some of the most cutting edge editions are still being put out one volume at a time, so be careful.

There are again too many important commentaries to list them all. Everyone needs to have a Mishnah Berurah. There are several good editions, but the Dirshu one seems to be taking over.

You should also get a Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (Artscroll and Metzudah put out translations) and a Chayei Adam. I also recommend Shulchan Aruch Harav and Aruch Hashulchan and Chazon Ish.

Next you'll want to buy everything by this author, for the best editions of the works listed [here](https://seforimcenter.com/Rabbi-Yechiel-Michel-Dzimitrovsky__c-p-0-0-735.aspx) for in-depth study.

If you are Sefardi, you should also get Ben Ish Chai, Kaf Hachayim, and Yalkut Yosef.

The best complete set IMO of Mishnah is Zecher Chanoch. For everyday use, most people probably use Kehati. Artscroll has two editions of Mishnah, one with a light commentary, and one called Yad Avraham. The latter is extremely thorough.

The best classic set of Rambam is this [one.](https://shabsifrankel.com/) But for the best non-classic set, get the [Qafih edition.](https://seforimcenter.com/Mishneh-Torah---RAMBAM-25-vol.---Kapach-Edition-__p-10353.aspx) More recent classic essays on Rambam are in Ohr Sameach, Chiddushei R' Chaim Halevi, and Chiddushei HaGri"z. The last two are the seminal works of the Brisker methodology of analysis.

Zohar: I would get this [set.](https://seforimcenter.com/Rabbi-Daniel-Frisch---Matok-MiDvash-1935-2005__c-p-0-0-364.aspx) The author used different fonts to separate the esoteric and non-esoteric parts of the Zohar.

Commentaries on Talmud Bavli: Ramban, Rashba, Ritva are crucial. Your overall best bet is to just get the Mossad Harav Kook editions. You also want to get Shittah Mekubetzes, Pnei Yehoshua, Chiddushei R' Akiva Eiger, and Chasam Sofer to start. Any new edition should be fine. Certain tractates have their own specific classic commentaries.

Try to find good sets of Midrash Rabbah and Midrash Tanchuma. Artscroll has a great Midrash Rabbah.

Get anything written by Rambam, Maharal, Ramchal, and Chafetz Chayim. Especially Derech Hashem. Also Nefesh Hachayim, [this edition.](https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/nefesh-hachaim/29897?gclid=CjwKCAiAxP2eBhBiEiwA5puhNU-LjoQvGZuuNeEcQXYnZMZ8i9d6I_mPy13qrylWgWUAsFvaZga35xoC_WwQAvD_BwE)

Some classic Responsa: Rashba, Rosh, Terumos Hadeshen, Noda Biyehudah, Rabbi Akiva Eiger, Chasam Sofer, Igros Moshe, Yabia Omer.

Comment: If you want to cheat, you could purchase Otzar Hachochmah for digital versions of most of these sefarim

Comment: This made me think of a story about R Yosi Wallis (in the artscroll book on him) where, at the beginning of his process of tshuva, he went into a Bnei Brak store, told the owner he needed a complete library, and started loading boxes after boxes into his station wagon ...

Comment: http://theseforimorganizers.com/services/#1545849220980-7d1ecc7b-ce90  offers a service of creating a library for you. If you are looking to go all out and spend that kind of money, such a service is a good idea.